# How to Enqueue JS Links in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to Enqueue these links in WP.

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js

As you can see that they are live links and are not in my WP Server. I know how to correctly enqueue JS files residing in my own server.

So how to enqueue those live links correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I perviously have answere similar question at [Wordpess.Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/173090/edit)

Its pretty simple.

First you have to add a function in your themes funcition.php file to register and enqueue your scripts in head using [wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook.

```
// Register and enqueue all scripts in head
function custom_scripts() {

    wp_register_script( 'script_to_validate', 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js', false, false, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script_to_validate' );

    wp_register_script( 'script_modernizr', 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js', false, false, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script_modernizr' );

}

// Hook into the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' action
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
```

Then you can call your function to initiate your script in footer using [wp_footer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) hook as following;

```
// Add this in function.php as well
function call_script_in_footer(){
?>
<script>
// Add your related script over here
</script>
<?php
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'call_script_in_footer' );
```

And thats it. Now you can use this in any template you want.

Comment: Ohh I see. So its basically same like we do with other JS files on server. Thank you Man :)

Comment: @InfiniteMystery If you found this answer helpful please vote up and mark it as correct answer.