# Enqueue External JS Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, widget, enqueue

I'm struggling to understand how to enqueue an external js file with some widget code within Wordpress. For example: there is a Frontapp chatbot that has to have the following code placed into the end of the  tag with my theme:

```
<script src="https://chat-assets.frontapp.com/v1/chat.bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  window.FrontChat('init', {chatId: '0xxxx', useDefaultLauncher: true});
</script>
```

How would I enqueue this since there's both an external link & snippet of Js?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Enqueue JS Links in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217412/how-to-enqueue-js-links-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_enqueue_script` for external scripts as well as `wp_add_inline_script` for inline scripts.

In your case that would be.

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-chat-assets', 'https://chat-assets.frontapp.com/v1/chat.bundle.js');
wp_add_inline_script('my-chat-assets', "window.FrontChat('init', {chatId: '0xxxx', useDefaultLauncher: true});");
```

Those lines should appear in `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook like all other enqueued scripts. If you want it at the footer, add `true` to the footer parameter. So all in all:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-chat-assets', 'https://chat-assets.frontapp.com/v1/chat.bundle.js', [], false, true);
    wp_add_inline_script('my-chat-assets', "window.FrontChat('init', {chatId: '0xxxx', useDefaultLauncher: true});");
});
```

Comment: Ty for this! Been trying to play around with using wp_add_inline_script but nothing is working on my end. Can I just use:

`wp_register_script( 'my-chat-assets', 'https://chat-assets.frontapp.com/v1/chat.bundle.js', [], '', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-chat-assets');
wp_add_inline_script('my-chat-assets', "window.FrontChat('init', {chatId: '0be7f8835374548fada14d2ca772a83a', useDefaultLauncher: true});"); `  
 for it to appear in my footer or do I need an add_action as well?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem.

```
add_action('wp_footer', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-chat-assets', 'https://chat-assets.frontapp.com/v1/chat.bundle.js', [], false, true);
    wp_add_inline_script('my-chat-assets', "window.FrontChat('init', {chatId: '0xxxx', useDefaultLauncher: true});");
});
```